# Aumentar width em % e não em px

Tags: javascript, jquery, progress-bar

Como faço pra aumentar o widht com %? Pôs esse código que fiz, ele aumenta, mas é em px, e queria que aumentasse em porcentagem.

```
var progressBar = $(".progress-bar");

setInterval(addProgress, 1000);

function addProgress() {
    var width = progressBar.width() + 10;
    if(progressBar.width() <= 100%) {
        progressBar.width(width);
    }
}
```

Pode ver que aquele `if` ali, não da certo, da erro. Como faço isso?

Comment: Aumentar o quê? O que é `.progress-bar`?

Comment: Ta vendo o progressBar.width() + 10, esse "10" vai ser em px, queria que fosse em %

Comment: Ok, jovem. Mas percentual em relação a quê?

Comment: Regra de 3? var max = 15445; var atual = XXXXX; progress_bar = (atual * 100)/max;

Comment: Oxe '-' acho que fui bem explicativo, no caso de eu não ter sido, desculpa. Mas isso .width() ali no meu código, vai acrescentar +10 pixels na width (Largura) do progressBar. Em vez de acrescentar 10pixels, eu queria acrescentar 10% (dez porcento)

Comment: Obrigado Everson, que burrice a minha. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

você também pode fazer a mesma coisa usando CSS.

```css
.progress-bar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 240px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border: 5px solid gainsboro
}

.progress-value {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: teal;
  animation: progress 5s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes progress {
    from { width: 0%; }
    to { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
  <div class="progress-value"></div>
</div>
```

você apenas precisa ajustar o tempo da sua animação, no exemplo acima está em 5 segundos.

Comment: Muito obrigado Tobias, nunca tinha visto o keyframes progress

Answer (score 1):

Exemplo funcional utilizando % retirado do [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_progressbar.asp)

Caso precise em progress pode comentar que edito a resposta.

```js
function move() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar"); 
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++; 
            elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: grey;
}
#myBar {
    width: 1%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="carregar" onclick="move()">
```

Comment: Obrigado, Mateus!